# unable to ping google.com from hyper-v installed freebsd instance

Tags: networking, hyper-v, freebsd

I'm trying to run FreeBSD on Hyper-V and it works BUT when I do ping google.com I get a `ping: Unknown host` error.

Here's what happens when I type in ifconfig:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP, LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet6 fe8::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        groups: lo
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINIKLOCAL>
hn0: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options-8051b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_TU,VLAN_HWTAGGNG,TSO4,LRO,LINKSTATE>
        ether 00:15:5d:01:26:18
        media: Ethernet autoelect (10Gbase-T <full-duplex>)
        status: active
        nd6 option=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

I have Network Adapter -> Virtual switch set to Default Switch if that helps.

When I ping my router (192.168.1.1) I get `ping: sendto: No route to host`.

I did `service dhclient restart hn0` and got the following:

```
dhclient not running? (check /var/run/dhclient/dhclient.hn0.pid).
'hn0' is not a DHCP-enabled interface
```

I've tried it with and without Network Adapter -> Advanced Features -> Enable MAC address spoofing checked.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you ping your router? what happens if you run a trace route?

Comment: @Albin - `ping: sendto: No route to host` (my router is at 192.168.1.1). For traceroute I get `traceroute: findsaddr: failed to connct to peer for src addr selection.`.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken your network interface should say UP (see loopback interface). What happens if you try `sudo ifconfig hn0 up`? what does  `ip link show` give you?

Comment: @Albin - `ifcofig hn0 up` ran without issue. When I tryto do sodo I get a `sudo: Command not found.` error. I get the same thing when I go `ip link show` as well

Comment: It seems that sudo has to be activated on FreeBSD. But if you have the necessary right to run the commands you don't need to worry about sudo. what did `ifconfig` and `ip link show` return?

Comment: Also, if you could post the configuration for the network adapter in Hyper-V, did you use the default switch? PS. if the command `ip link show` doesn't work I think the equivalent ifconfig command is `ifconfig -a`), otherwise you could also install the appropriate package in order to use the ip command.

Comment: @Albin - here's my ifconfig output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lKFc.jpg When I type in `ip link show` I get `ip: Command not found.`. `ifconfig -a` shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ROoX.jpg . I can't install packages because the network isn't working. eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u8ss.jpg

Comment: @Albin - Hyper-V network settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F666N.jpg and (Hardware Acceleration settings) https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ6yQ.jpg and (Advanced Features settings) https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1VHg.jpg

Comment: Do you have `ifconfig_hn0="DHCP"` in `/etc/rc.conf`: https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/13.0-RELEASE/usr/local/share/doc/freebsd/en/books/handbook/config-network-setup.html

Comment: Try to add the following to `/etc/rc.conf `: `ifconfig_hn0="SYNCDHCP"` and reboot.

Comment: @neubert the problem is that your networkcard isn't configured with neither an IP and a  gateway (either static or set by dhcp). the ip settings for the networkcard should be set to DHCP by default with the standard iso image. Spoofing the Mac is also disabled by default for hyper-v. Check for the card settings as tom yan suggested. If it's still set to dhcp, it might be easier for you to just setup a new VM without the changes (or somekind of funky setup) - I assume - you made.

Comment: @neubert please add the configurations into your question not into the comments, having to click each of them in the comments in unbearable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell (the OP currently doesn't respond) the solution was to "enable" the virtual network card on the VM using `ifcofig hn0 up`.

This is assuming the virtual network adapter was set up correctly. The standard setting to enable internet access is the `default switch` as a virtual switch for the network adapter. Make sure it's up and running via `ncpa.cpl` (the IP address assigned to the default switch should be the default gateway assigned within the OS of the VM).

Also check for the correct network interface configuration. The file `/etc/rc.conf` holds the settings for the network card (in your case `hn0`). There should be a line `ifconfig_hn0="DHCP"` which sets the NIC to receive it's configuration from the DHCP server. With a standard installation (using the "default switch" when creating the VM) this setting should be there by default. If it's not you can add it manually (if it's not the problem has a different cause). However it's likely that s.th. went wrong during the installation / was reconfigured afterwards and it might be easier to just reinstall the whole thing instead of doing the trouble shooting procedure.

You can do a test and connect the VM via an "external switch": Add as second network card to the VM and bind it to an external switch. This will add the VM as a node in your "physical LAN" which should give the VM access to the  internet as well. If you do not have an DHCP server in your LAN make sure to configure the second virtual network adapter manually via the `/etc/rc.conf` otherwise use the DHCP configuration as shown above (the second network adapter is usually named `hn1`).

Comment: I do intend to respond but I also have other stuff going on in my life, too, and I'm not going to drop everything I'm doing every time I get a response to an SO post and test it out..

Comment: @neubert thanks for your reply, glad you didn't abandon the post... I'll wait for your response then.

Comment: I responded to your post with more info. Thanks!